# How to compile an HTML file to run as an application

Tags: html, compile

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I'm wondering if its possible to turn an HTML, CSS, and JavaScript file into an executable application that doesn't run in the browser.  I'll also accept methods for windows, as I've installed the WINE compatibility package.

Comment: Wine isn't perfect; in fact, it's far from it. I don't think you'll get the results you expect by using wine.

Comment: Yes, by writing your own browser ...

Comment: Hi Christian - what you're looking for is to create HTML applications (*.hta) so head over to Microsoft to get started > https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Electron. I personally don't use it, but it sounds right up your alley.

https://electronjs.org/

As you mention you are open to Windows options, check out HTA (HTML applications) though this is now considered "legacy" and it may not work forever, but isn't "compiled" as it would be with other solutions.